# Getting singular value from a array that is deep(nested ig?)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Honestly I am just trying to figure out how to get a value from Member, but I can't figure out how. ![This is how it is setup.][1]

Edit: I just need the value itself.  I don't know how to get it, so any help would be appreciated.

```
data = new to({
    guildid: message.guild.id,
    Members: [{
        Member: message.author.tag,
        MemberID: message.author.id,
        Type_ args[0]
    }]
})
```

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Wouldn't it be `data.Members[0].Member`?

Comment: that makes a new field tho doesnt it?

Comment: @EganWolf yea you were right lmaoo

Comment: Your image reference is missing. Either add a valid URL or remove `![This is how it is setup.][1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data.Members[0].Member`. There is an array in `data.Members` so you must specify the element of the array you want to retrieve.